# How to escape minus sign in Java Formatter?

Tags: java, string, formatting, command-line-interface

Here is formatted table headers example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);
formatter.format("%-16s ---%-21s--- %-21s %-23s %-25s", "IP", "BLOCKED", "BLOCKED TILL", "ACTIVITY (00:00-24:00)", "COUNTRY");
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

But the problem is at `---%-21s---` part:

```
IP               ---BLOCKED              --- BLOCKED TILL          ACTIVITY (00:00-24:00)  COUNTRY
```

How to escape last three minus signs? I want to emphasize sorted column. The result should be like:

```
IP               ---BLOCKED---               BLOCKED TILL          ACTIVITY (00:00-24:00)  COUNTRY
```

Comment: Last `---` don't require escaping since they are printed as expected. It just happens that before them you reserved space for minimum 21 characters. If you want to place those `---` withing that reserved space you need to pass them as part of *value*, not *format*.

Comment: But is it still possible to do that at _format_ part?

Comment: No, unless you create some other method which will generate unique formats based on values (like length of passed value), but that kind of defeats purpose of Formatter.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you specified the `BLOCKED` string to have a width of 21, so the dashes `---` can't immediately surround the text (note how the second set of dashes comes after a bunch of spaces). Instead, you have to put the dashes inside the string to be printed:

```
formatter.format("%-16s %-21s %-21s %-23s %-25s", "IP", "---BLOCKED---", "BLOCKED TILL", "ACTIVITY (00:00-24:00)", "COUNTRY");
```

Comment: Yes, I did it before the answer.. silly me :) But thanks anyway.

Comment: Perhaps better solution is to use just `-/\-BLOCKED` in ascending order or `-\/-BLOCKED`.